# What are the main elements to strive towards?

Tags: dont-starve-together

Started a game with friends and frankly, after 2 3-hour sessions, I have about 0 idea what I'm supposed to do to progress. Created a few weapons, armors, that didn't feel they did a huge difference.

So what are the main things I should be working towards? (Spoiler free as possible)

What are the main steps that will build you up towards the ending if there is any?

Or is Don't starve together a game simply without a 'final objective' and it's just survive as long as you find it interesting?